# I need to open external links as modal box but those links are located in external link which opens as modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

kind of nested modal box for external links issue ,I had used the following code successfully to load external page in modal box but I cannot load external links inside that modal to open them as modal box the same way because I want it to be opened by default if the user opened it out of modal box

```
<div id="Site" class="modal fade page-load" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center">
                <div data-role="page">
                    <div class="Popup">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#Site .Popup").load("Site.html");
</script>
```

Comment: why I do not get any answer

Comment: Probably because we can't make sense of your question...

Comment: you are not allowed to open modal window from modal window, thats the purpose of modal window

Comment: so you have some links in Site.html which are to be opened as modal when you open Site.html as a dialog box/modal? Can you edit the code in Site.html ? I mean do you have control over Site.html or is it some page developed by others which you can't edit?

Comment: thank you for your help ,I found the answer was so simple I just loaded the the link in iframe into the modal box so I could open all external links in the same modal